# Finding the average of dataframe column only until end of day (datetime-indexed)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` object that is indexed by `datetime`. Let us say my object looks like this:

```
 DateTime              A
 2016-07-01 08:30:00   5
 2016-07-01 09:28:17   6
 2016-07-01 14:09:11   9
 2016-07-01 22:33:44   10
 2016-07-02 08:30:00   20
 2016-07-02 15:00:00   30
```

I want to make a new column that has the mean of column A calculated only from data points (rows) that have a timestamp until the end of the day. In this example, the resulting dataframe object would look like this:

```
 DateTime              A    B
 2016-07-01 08:30:00   5    7.5
 2016-07-01 09:28:17   6    8.33333
 2016-07-01 14:09:11   9    9.5
 2016-07-01 22:33:44   10   10
 2016-07-02 08:30:00   20   25
 2016-07-02 15:00:00   30   30
```

I have thought to make a separate column to get the end of the day, slice the data by time (`df['A'].loc[df['DateTime']:df['end_of_day']].mean()`) but I have found that you can't variably slice the data based on a series of data. Does anyone have any efficient ways to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom function to `apply` with

```
def nowTilEODMean(d):
    cond1 = df.index >= d.name
    cond2 = df.index.day == d.name.day
    return df.A.loc[cond1 & cond2].mean()

df['B'] = df.apply(nowTilEODMean, axis=1)
df
```

[image]